# Admin doesn't see subscription

Tags: azure

I made Azure order (MS-AZR-0145P or 146 for sandbox) for my customer.

Partner Center Api response said I have active subscription.

I logged in Azure Portal as my customer admin, but there were no subscription.

How to make subscription visible in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Customer don't get Azure subscription management rights automatically.
Partner admin can grant rights to customer user.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2016/06/08/identity-and-rights-management-in-csp-model/